# How to use "mesh" in kivy file instead on python file

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, mesh

I am trying to draw a custom shape with kivy using "mesh" in python.
I did some research on this but most of the result is just write the code in the python file

The code from [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/examples/gen__canvas__mesh__py.html) and [here](https://blog.kivy.org/2014/01/kivy-image-manipulations-with-mesh-and-textures/) shows the way to construct mesh object in the python file but i found a problem when i try to translate it into kivy file

this is the code in my main file(main.py):

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.graphics import Mesh
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class MainScreen(Screen):
    Mesh = ObjectProperty(None)

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("health.kv")

sample_app = TestApp()
sample_app.run()
```

and this is the code in my kivy file(test.kv):

```
<MainScreen>:
    name: "main"
    Mesh:
        vertices: [0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100, 0, 0]
        indices: [0, 1, 2]
```

The error goes as below:

```
File "C:\Users\kelv1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\floatlayout.py", line 135, in add_widget
 widget.bind(
AttributeError: 'kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions.Mesh' object has no attribute 'bind'
```

Why does it happens and how to solve it??

Comment: the version of my python and kivy is 3.7.0 and 1.10.1 respectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forgot to put it into a canvas. And I added the `triangle_fan` mode, to make it into  polygon. Just guessing that is what you want.
Try this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

KV = """

<MainScreen@Screen>:
    name: "main"
    canvas:
        Mesh:
            mode: "triangle_fan"
            vertices: [0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100, 0, 0]
            indices: [0, 1, 2]

MainScreen:

"""


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


MyApp().run()
```